# Java: clone arbitrary Collection through reference to Collection

Tags: java, collections

Suppose you've a reference of type `java.util.Collection` in a method and cannot say what implementation of `java.util.Collection` will it point to at run time, is it possible to clone the Collection?

I wanted to implement a generic method which will filter any type of collection given. Hence the method will take `java.util.Collection` as input. However beyond this, I didn't want to modify the original collection, so I wanted to clone the collection.

Comment: Why do you need your output collection to be the same type as the input one?

Comment: Should the original collection stay unmodified?

Comment: @Nicolas: Matter of convenience :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three options:

1. <strike>Rely on the collection's own `clone` method (assuming it implements `Cloneable`) and then remove the undesired elements.</strike> *Edit:* As pointed out in the comments and other answers, `clone()` is not public and therefore is not accessible.
2. Ask the caller to provide an empty collection to copy the target elements between source and destination.
3. Define a factory interface to create an empty collection and ask the caller to provide a factory implementation. Then copy the target elements between source and destination.

Comment: see my comment on michael post about the clone method and the cloneabl interface.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunaly the interface Collection does not say anything about implementing Clonable Interface.

---

But what you can always do is copy the collection:

```
List<T> copy = new ArrayList<T>(original);
```

---

If you only want to make sure that it is not modified then wrap it with an unmodidfiable collection instead of cloning it:

```
Collection<T> unmodifiable = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(original);
```

Comment: Quite a few of the implementations of `Collection` do, so th `instanceof` method would work for many cases.

Comment: Look at comment on other answers: Cloneable does not mean that you can use the clone method.

Comment: The reference to the unmodifiable collection will remain local, the original collection is still modifiable by references outside, I wanted to modify a copy of the original collection and return it.

Comment: @Nicloas: my fault - i removed this part of the answer

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to demonstrate in Scala, becuase it has a REPL where I can test, but the same semantics should work in Java.

```
import java.util._
val orig = new LinkedList[Int]
val theClone = orig.clone
```

The Scala REPL tells me that theClone has static type `Object` (you can cast this to `Collection[Int]` or `LinkedList[Int]`), but the dynamic type of the clone is still `LinkedList`.

Now I suppose what you want is a method that returns a static type `LinkedList` when it recieves a static type `LinkedList` and returns a static type `ArrayList` when it recieves a static type `ArrayList`, etc. in which case

```
def doClone[C <: Collection[_]](orig:C) = {
  val cloneMethod = orig.getClass.getDeclaredMethod("clone")
  if (cloneMethod.isAccessible)
    cloneMethod.invoke(orig).asInstanceOf[C]
  else
    throw new CloneNotSupportedException
}
```

In Java, I think that's

```
<C extends Collection<?> > C doClone (C orig) {
   java.lang.reflect.Method cloneMethod = 
     orig.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("clone");
   if (cloneMethod.isAccessible())
     return (C) cloneMethod.invoke(orig);
   else
     throw new CloneNotSupportedException();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really, really, really, really need to do this, there is an ugly hack.

```
  public static <T> T tryToClone(T object)
      throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    Object clone = null;

    // Use reflection, because there is no other way
    try {
      Method method = object.getClass().getMethod("clone");
      clone = method.invoke(object);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
      rethrow(e.getCause());
    } catch (Exception cause) {
      rethrow(cause);
    }
    if (object.getClass().isInstance(clone)) {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // clone class <= object class <= T
      T t = (T) clone;
      return t;
    } else {
      throw new ClassCastException(clone.getClass().getName());
    }
  }

  private static void rethrow(Throwable cause)
      throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    if (cause instanceof RuntimeException) {
      throw (RuntimeException) cause;
    }
    if (cause instanceof Error) {
      throw (Error) cause;
    }
    if (cause instanceof CloneNotSupportedException) {
      throw (CloneNotSupportedException) cause;
    }
    CloneNotSupportedException e = new CloneNotSupportedException();
    e.initCause(cause);
    throw e;
  }
```

Comment: FYI, this comes from here: http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/base/Objects.java?spec=svn16&r=9 -- we later deleted it, because it is a terrible no-good useless dirty hacky hack.

Answer (score 1):

Better filter the collection by modifying it in your method. Up to the caller to provide you with the original collection or a proper copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

In theory it is possible with reflection, however not all `Collection` implementations can (or should) be instantiated this way. A prime example is a result of `Collections.singletonList()`, which has no public constructors at all. Other special collections can raise other issues too.

What I would do instead is to just check the interfaces the input collection implements and return a "default" implementation for that type. So for example:

```
Collection c = ...
if( c instanceof SortedSet )
  return new TreeSet( c );
if( c instanceof Set )
  return new HashSet( c );
```

Ans so on.

Comment: Tomorrow any one can implement Collection.

Answer (score 0):

If the collection implements `Cloneable`, you can do it. You wouldn't have to worry about the exact type; the collection's `clone()` implementation would take care of that.

Comment: Object.clone() is protected. You can't simply call it if you don't know the object's real type. Well, maybe you can do it using reflection as biziclop suggested in his answer.

Comment: Fixed that issue - forgot you needed to implement `cloneable` and override `clone()`.

Comment: Even if you implement `Cloneable`, the clone method may not be public, see the javadoc http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html

Comment: Yes, see @Ralph's answer for solution to that. (I think)